# Are hardware support questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Can I ask about Ubuntu native (just plug it in) hardware support here?
I didn't see the word "hardware" on the tour. If this isn't the correct place, where should I ask?

If it *IS* on topic, can that be added to the tour please?

Comment: That's kind of a broad question about questions!  People often ask about a specific problem with a specific piece of hardware, hoping that someone will have experience with it and that often does work.  If you post a generic "What's the best graphics..." then your question will probably be close as being too broad or primarily opinion based.  I'd go ahead and try your question, though!

Comment: I will move this to meta once it lets me.

Comment: @CharlesGreen that's fair. I often have a very specific need and find conflicting information after doing my research, and can't get a clear answer if there even is a solution. I'm not looking for best - just functional, and even so the pool is often minimal to not-clear-if-it-exists outside of Windows support.

Comment: I looked through meta-askubuntu briefly, and find that they don't like 'hardware shopping' related question and stack-exchange - diagnosing and fixing are a different matter.  You might also consider throwing out a question about this topic on the [AskUbuntu general chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Comment: Ah - I see you did that!

Comment: The problem is this is often a reoccurring issue for people and by forcing it to go to chat or other transient locations, the information is repeatedly lost. I have unanswered forum posts on other sites which have closed with no responses or searches on google which pull up my questions from a decade ago as the best result... just with a lot of "me too" and "did anyone ever figure this out" type posts.

Comment: Maybe at [hardwarerecs](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), another SE site?

Comment: Note if your question is "Does ABC123 work on Ubuntu?" and ABC123 is a specific piece of hardware there is a chance your quesiton will be closed as broad, unclear, or will just go unanswered or have half-effort answers.  There's no guarantee vague questions like this are answerable here on Ask Ubuntu.  As for hardware *recommendation* requests, those are offtopic and belong on the Hardware Recs site that Charles linked,

Answer (score 3):

A huge number of questions on Ask Ubuntu are about hardware support. Most of the questions tagged [wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless) and [drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/drivers) and many other questions with broad tags such as [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) are hardware-specific.

You will find many questions along the lines of

> How do I get this particular {printer scanner soundcard webcam Bluetooth-headset} to work with Ubuntu?

Obviously these questions are on topic :)